# Laravel - How to get data from another relation table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 4 table like this:

```
quizzes
id | title

questions
id | question

question_quiz
id | quiz_id | question_id

question_options
id | question_id | option | is_answer
```

quiz model

```
/**
 * Get the questions for the quiz.
 */
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question');
}
```

question model

```
/**
 * Get the question options for the question.
 */
public function question_options()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\QuestionOption');
}
```

How do quizzes table can retrieve data from the question_options table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have model Name for a quiz is Quiz then this might help you. This will give you all related option for questions which belongs to Quiz.

```
Quiz::with('questions.question_options')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Quiz::with('questions.question_options')->where('status', 'ACTIVE')->get();
```

Using this you can get the questions and the question_options of that question

and the response would be

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: quiz,
        questions: [{
            id: 1,
            question: question,
            question_options: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    question_id: question,
                    option: option 1
                    is_answer: 1
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    question_id: question,
                    option: option 2
                    is_answer: 0
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    question_id: question,
                    option: option 3
                    is_answer: 0
                },
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```